# how to make vuetify dialog draggable

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui, vuetify.js

I need to make a draggable dialog. But I'm using Vue2 & Vuetify.

I tried using jquery but doesn't work.

index.html

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $(".my-custom-dialog").draggable();
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

App.vue

```html
<v-dialog v-model="isOpen" content-class="my-custom-dialog">
  <!-- dialog content-->
</v-dialog>
```

I thought using `content-class` to give my dialog class name and using jquery as above would work. But it doesn't. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [vue-dialogue-drag](https://github.com/emiliorizzo/vue-dialog-drag), it is a pretty small package, and I usually recommend avoiding those (read about it at the end of the comment).
It's relatively easy to use, and you can follow the instruction in its GitHub readme.

if you would like to implement a solution written by you, you can use this as a template:

```
(function () { // make vuetify dialogs movable
    const d = {};
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        const closestDialog = e.target.closest(".v-dialog.v-dialog--active");
        if (e.button === 0 && closestDialog != null && e.target.classList.contains("v-card__title")) { // element which can be used to move element
            d.el = closestDialog; // element which should be moved
            d.mouseStartX = e.clientX;
            d.mouseStartY = e.clientY;
            d.elStartX = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            d.elStartY = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            d.el.style.position = "fixed";
            d.el.style.margin = 0;
            d.oldTransition = d.el.style.transition;
            d.el.style.transition = "none"
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        if (d.el === undefined) return;
        d.el.style.left = Math.min(
            Math.max(d.elStartX + e.clientX - d.mouseStartX, 0),
            window.innerWidth - d.el.getBoundingClientRect().width
        ) + "px";
        d.el.style.top = Math.min(
            Math.max(d.elStartY + e.clientY - d.mouseStartY, 0),
            window.innerHeight - d.el.getBoundingClientRect().height
        ) + "px";
    });
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        if (d.el === undefined) return;
        d.el.style.transition = d.oldTransition;
        d.el = undefined
    });
    setInterval(() => { // prevent out of bounds
        const dialog = document.querySelector(".v-dialog.v-dialog--active");
        if (dialog === null) return;
        dialog.style.left = Math.min(parseInt(dialog.style.left), window.innerWidth - dialog.getBoundingClientRect().width) + "px";
        dialog.style.top = Math.min(parseInt(dialog.style.top), window.innerHeight - dialog.getBoundingClientRect().height) + "px";
    }, 100);
})();
```

- According to [deps.dev](https://deps.dev/npm/vue-dialog-drag) `vue-dialogue-drag` has a 4.8/10 safety rate though there are no dangerous workflows within it, I believe that the reason for the low score is lack of updates :)

Answer (score 1):

To make **Vuetify 3.+** dialogs movable you may use solution earlier suggested by **tipsy** at https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4058 (identical to the accepted answer) but tailored as Vue component `movable.vue` which you import into your `App.vue`.

```
<script>
/* add class .vss-movable to <v-card-title> to make a dialog movable */

(function () {
  const d = {}
  const isMovable = (targ) => {
    return targ.classList?.contains("vss-movable")
  }
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    const closestDialog = e.target.closest(".v-overlay__content")
    const title = closestDialog?.querySelector(".v-card-title")
    if ( e.button === 0 && closestDialog != null && (isMovable(e.target)) || isMovable(e.target.parentNode) ) {
      d.el = closestDialog // movable element
      d.handle = title // enable dlg to be moved down beyond bottom
      d.mouseStartX = e.clientX
      d.mouseStartY = e.clientY
      d.elStartX = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().left
      d.elStartY = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().top
      d.el.style.position = "fixed"
      d.el.style.margin = 0
      d.oldTransition = d.el.style.transition
      d.el.style.transition = "none"
    }
  })
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    if (d.el === undefined) return
    d.el.style.left = Math.min(
      Math.max(d.elStartX + e.clientX - d.mouseStartX, 0),
      window.innerWidth - d.el.getBoundingClientRect().width
    ) + "px"
    d.el.style.top = Math.min(
      Math.max(d.elStartY + e.clientY - d.mouseStartY, 0),
      window.innerHeight - d.handle.getBoundingClientRect().height
    ) + "px"
  })
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (d.el === undefined) return
    d.el.style.transition = d.oldTransition
    d.el = undefined
  })
})()
</script>

<style>
.v-overlay.v-dialog .vss-movable {
  cursor: grab;
}
.v-overlay.v-dialog .vss-movable:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.v-overlay.v-dialog .vss-movable:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
</style>
```

Comment: hi! Could you explain a bit more how to implement this? I copied the code and wanted to make "modal dialogs" draggable but it's very glitchy. Or maybe I misunderstood how to use.. I used v-dialog-drag for vue2 but now I don't know how to implement something similar for vue3..